# How to run Java code in in beashell of jmeter and pass vairables in Jmeter script

Tags: jar, jmeter, beanshell

Hi I am getting the following error:

```
2020-05-22 18:46:34,329 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import java.io.FileInputStream; import java.util.Base64; im . . . '' Encountered "[" at line 16, column 40.
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

        String imageString = null;
        String pathImageFolder = "/home/sarvesh/Desktop/sgi/10";

        File file = new File(pathImageFolder);
        int filecount = file.list().length;
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        for (File f : files) {

            f = new File(f.getPath());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            byte byteArray[] = new byte[(int) f.length()];
            fis.read(byteArray);
            imageString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);

            System.out.println("***********************************************");
            System.out.println("File Path     :   " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Base 64 Image : " + imageString);
            System.out.println("***********************************************");

        }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Typo, change to `byte []byteArray`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [staring from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting therefore consider migrating to the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) on next available opportunity, the equivalent code would be something like:

```
String pathImageFolder = "/home/sarvesh/Desktop/sgi/10";
new File(pathImageFolder).listFiles().each { file ->
    imageString = file.bytes.encodeBase64().toString();
    log.info("File Path     :" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    log.info("Base 64 Image :" + imageString);
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Base64 Encoding](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-base64-encoding.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)